# Vanilla JavaScript Routing and Image Preloading

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have the following piece of a partial view in HTML as exterior.html file:

```
<div class="layout-exterior">

      <div id="carExterior" class="cars-exterior-1"></div>
      <div class="icon-360-black"></div>
      <div class="swipe-to-experience-black"></div>

</div>
```

On 'touchmove' event it changes the background in relation to its current position, but it's not the problem.

The problem is I can only use Vanilla Javascript in my company (no jQuery, so no built-in promises) and when I include this into the main index.html template's main container, the preloading script in index.html loses binding to the script which results in images not being preloaded and they 'blink' on the first load. Tried putting them in the bottom and the head, same outcome.

I utilise simple routing that checks hash on hashchange and then loads for instance exteriorView function that, in turn, fetches template content via AJAX get request.

Now, I was thinking about preloading them CSS way; sprite them away and then sprite them back in, but it is not allowed where I work for.

Including preload script in the partial template still does not work (putting images in .src of new Image()). Used the following script:

```
<div class="hidden">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
            var images = new Array()
            function preload() {
                for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
                    images[i] = new Image()
                    images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
                }
            }
            preload(
                "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-001.jpg",
                "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-002.jpg",
                "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-003.jpg"
            )
        //--><!]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

Does anyone know any solution for that?

Comment: try `arguments` instead of `preload.arguments`

Comment: I dont think this is an issue, i mean it is function calls itself recursively, and this works everywhere else, but not when I dynamically load content